# Call each function in the list

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've got an array of functions and looking for a concise way to call each one in order.

```
fns = [
    function a() { console.log('a') },
    function b() { console.log('b') },
    function c() { console.log('c') },
]
```

this works:

```
fns.map(function (f) { f() })
```

and so does this:

```
fns.map(function (f) { Function.call.call(f) })
```

however this raises a TypeError:

```
fns.map(Function.call.call)
```

Why doesn't the latter example work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simplified code exhibits a similar issue:

```
var x = Function.call.call;
x(alert);
```

In this case, once `Function.call.call` gets called, it won't remember the context from which it originated (i.e. `Function.call`). To save this context, you could use this <strike>unholy construct</strike> trick:

```
Function.call.bind(Function.call)
```

It returns a new function whereby the context of `Function.call` is bound to itself, thus saving the context. You can save this expression in a new variable:

```
var callFn = Function.call.bind(Function.call);
```

Now, `callFn(alert)` is identical to `alert.call()`. Note that any additional arguments will be passed along as is, so `callFn(alert, window)` will invoke `alert.call(window)`. Understanding this behaviour is important in situations when `callFn` gets called as part of a callback such as `Array.forEach`, whereby three arguments are passed in each iteration.

```
fns.forEach(callFn);
```

In your case, none of the functions inside `fns` are using the arguments that are passed, but behind the scenes they're called like this:

```
fns[0].call(0, fns)
```

So `this` equals the element's index (i.e. `Number(0)`) and `arguments[0]` equals the array of functions. The keen observer may have noticed that the element's value falls in between the cracks, though it may still be referenced using `arguments[0][this]` or, alternatively, `arguments.callee` (deprecated).

Comment: Good follow-up about arguments, but why `callee`? What's wrong with simply `arguments[0][this]`?

Comment: @thg435 That's a good point; that would work in this case :) updated, with thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
for (var i = 0, len = fns.length; i < len; i++) {
    fns[i].call();
};
```

Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/BUAA3/).

Use `Function.prototype.call` and `Function.prototype.apply` as above to call a function. With `call` and `apply` you can pass execution scope and `arguments` to the function call. If you don't need that, you can simply do:

```
for (var i = 0, len = fns.length; i < len; i++) {
        fns[i]();
};
```

**About your code:**

`Array.prototype.map` is a function that takes `callback` and `scope as parameters`. In the first two examples, you are using an anonymous function as the `callback` and you call the parameter passed to it automatically by `Array.prototype.map`. To expand, your code is the equivalent of this:

```
function single(element) {
   element();
};
fns.map(single);
```

So the above is entirely correct. Following the same principle by using `Function.call.call`, you are calling the function `f` passed as a parameter by map.

But in your third example you are forcing a direct `call` via `Function.call.prototype.call`, however in this case, `f` no longer gets passed as a parameter, which means your `Function.call.call` will attempt to call `undefined`, hence you get the `TypeError`. When you put `Function.call.call` inside `map()`, you are **NOT** passing a `callback` as an argument.

The `call` will be immediately. `Function.call.call` is the exact same thing as `Function.call.call()`, or `Function.call.call(undefined)`, which will be immediately evaluated when used as you did in your third example.

Comment: The OP most likely already knows all this. The question asks *why*, not *how*.

Comment: I was actually writing up the same in the meantime! +1

Answer (score 3):

The `TypeError` occurs because `Function.prototype.call` internally invokes `this` (with the given context and parameters, but that's not important in the discussion).

Let's rewrite the working

```
fns.map(function (f) { Function.call.call(f) })
```

as the equivalent

```
fns.map(function (f) {
    var invoker = Function.call;
    invoker.call(f);
})
```

It is now obvious that `invoker` is invoked with `f` as `this`. When it internally tries to invoke `this` in turn your function is called, as expected.

Now look at this:

```
fns.map(Function.call.call);
```

and the equivalent form

```
fns.map(function (f) {
    var invoker = Function.call;
    invoker.call();
})
```

It should be obvious that here, when `invoker` is invoked `this` is `undefined`; therefore it cannot be invoked itself and this gives rise to the `TypeError`.